# git: prohibit to accidentally push merge testing into master

Tags: git, push

there are some repositories (one-per-indepndent-module fashion) in gitosis

two branches: master (production receives updates from this branch) and testing

- task: for every repository deny attempts to screw up master branch: 
  prohibit pushing testing into master merge
- situation: recently migrated from svn to git

everybody have local clone and a local branch for every bug

he merges it into testing (our integration branch), then, if qa approves, deploys (merges into master and push)

not much manpower, like one most active person per repository

who knows what happening there - he is a git newbie, like I am

We need central integration branch and ready to use production branch as soon as possible, but cannot afford separate man just to do this integration.

Person who wrote the code is responsible for merging it into testing and deploy after testing done on another, integration webapp instance (different from developer mashine)

- goal: protect from this main developer screw ups

---

I am thinking to write an update hook which detects ref being pushed

and looks through messages of pushed commits

https://gist.github.com/23b807f29c37c5699670

yeah this is ugly

some developers push from their clones manually, some aren't

maybe I should ensure everybody to use deploy script which takes task branch name and show list of pushed commits before merging it into master and pushing it

---

any ideas

- to prohibit merge testing into master via a hook in central repository
- to prohibit merge testing into master via a hook at developer mashine

Comment: Consider moving to gitolite as gitosis is no longer actively developed. Works the same way but you get the benefit of new features and good support for current versions of Git.

Answer (score 1):

If everyone is pushing to one central repo, you'll get most of the problems of non-distributed version systems.

The distributed way of doing it is: Let only those you trust (e.g. you and Linus etc.) have write access to the "canonical" repository. Let all other users have their own public mirror of their own repo (one that only they can push to, and everyone can pull from) that the trusted user(s) can pull from, then push to the canonical repo. Problem solved.

Comment: see updated question. Right way to this is to transform every module (repo) lead developer to Linus in terms of git expertise. In the mean time I should make everybody use same deploy script AND establish some boundaries to prohibit obvious screw-ups (it is second time one happened)

Answer (score 0):

I would only restrict this on the central repository. Local development can roll with the punches and push to a different branch if they need at the time.

What you are missing in the hook is checking the user. Add that to ensure that /someone/ can push to master.

Alternatively, make another repo and give only yourself and whoever else write access by modifying the config. This would not require you to use hooks at all.